# Looking for a crappy email client

Tags: email, html-email, plaintext

I wrote some code to send email as both HTML & Text, and I am having having trouble testing it.

On Thunderbird and Outlook, there is an option to view as plain-text, however I have a feeling that they are being smart and doing something to the plain text (because it looks slightly different in thunderbird than in outlook).

What's the crappiest email client out there? One that simply has no HTML support and would not be smart enough to convert HTML to text by itself.

I'd like to see the worst solution.

Comment: haha, interesting question. I'd like to see some answers (unfortunately I don't have any).

Comment: Could it just be the fonts/size of fonts/size of viewport difference?

Comment: Am I too late to recommend Outlook Express 6? The only thing that is more crappy than it's email support is it's newsgroup support :)

Comment: https://www.mail-tester.com/ will show you both the text/html and text/plain versions of your email. It runs a bunch of other useful tests, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**mail**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mail) on *nix is an option. Use it on a terminal, and there's no way you'll get automatic conversion of HTML!

( If *mail* is ***too crappy***, you can try another text based email client, that is actually easy to use and often installed - [Alpine](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/acquire/) ( although, if you want to err on the side of ***crappy*** go for [Pine](http://www.washington.edu/pine/) instead ) )

Comment: How do I do that? I have access to a linux machine but does that mean I need to create an email account hosted on that machine and setup some MX servers and such?

Comment: @nute - I have never used `mail`... it's **crappy** like you wanted. I have used `Alpine` which is actually quite easy to use, and also text based... but it's not all that crappy imo ;)

Comment: Alpine is awesome and the perfect match for what I was looking for. And they have a Windows binary.

Answer (score 5):

Lotus Notes.  Even simple HTML is likely to be mauled. This would be a perfect application, and the only suitable purpose it could possibly fulfill.  While you're at it, you can get a great example of how to design a bad interface.

Are you dealing with technical people with this?  I can't imagine many people use something like Mutt except for CS professors and people who read SO, but realistically not many common readers (other than internal company email at places with limited computers like POS systems) use non-HTML mail.

Also, look into how it looks without externally linked images because most webmail providers (and others) block it.

Answer (score 3):

The view plain text option in Thunderbird actually displays the plain text copy from the Multi-part MIME.  That should be fine for what you're looking to do.

Outlook actually converts the HTML version into plain text and does not show the plain text version that was delivered in the MIME.

Bottom line, just use Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to test your mail in both outlook 2003 and 2007.

**Outlook 2003** uses ***Internet Explorer*** to render HTML mails.

**Outlook 2007** uses ***Word*** to render HTML mails. It doesn't support stuff like positioning of elements, so if you heavily rely on css, outlook 2007 is going mess things up for sure.

Comment: Outlook 2010 uses Word 2010, which is again slightly different than Word 2007 :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually see the Text part of a multi-part email (an email sent with both an HTML version and a Text version in the same message), then I'd recommend having a look at [Fastmail.fm](http://www.fastmail.fm/).  They have an option to show nothing but the Text part of the multipart.

If on the other hand you are looking for an email client with the worst heuristics to convert HTML to Text - then I'm going to take a guess and second Lotus Notes.

Comment: My goal is a client that will simply show the text version. I don't want it to try to convert the html for me. I'm gonna take a look at fastmail. Really the ideal would be some mobile phone email client from the old generation, but I don't have any ...

Comment: And Yes, FastMail shows the same as Thunderbird, which seems to be the real plain text. Outlook is trying to be smart and changed my text.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for [elm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm_%28e-mail_client%29) or [pine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_%28e-mail_client%29) on *nix - both very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to see what the message actually is (not just what it looks like) in Thunderbird, I just use the [view message source](http://email.about.com/od/mozillatips/qt/et043001.htm) option. That gives me the plain text and the HTML source.

If you just want mangled e-mail, though, Lotus Notus is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Mail on *nix. Very, VERY crappy.